# golang make struct T implement I but not *T

Tags: go

I have a struct T that implements an interface I, but I want *T to *not* implement the interface. Is this possible?

That is, this should compile fine:

```
var obj I = T{}
```

but this should generate a compile error:

```
var obj I = &T{}
```

The reason is that it is a common mistake in my codebase to accidentally use *T as a certain interface I when it is expected that only T will be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not possible. From the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) (emphasis mine):

> A type may have a method set associated with it. The method set of an interface type is its interface. The method set of any other type T consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. **The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T** (that is, it also contains the method set of T).